# How do "first spouses" work in European parliamentary systems?

Tags: political-leaders

Up to now, the wives of American Presidents have been known as First Ladies, although if Mrs. Clinton wins in November, a certain former President will be the "First Gentleman."

But European parliamentary systems often have two leaders, the head of state and the head of government. They are the President and Premier in France, and the President and Chancellor in Germany. In those instances, whose spouse gets to be "First Spouse" or are both spouses "First Spouses?"

And would the title for Herr Merkel or M. Cresson be "First Gentleman," or something else?

Comment: Europeans in general are way less obsessed about the personal life of their PM/Presidents, the exception generally being monarchs. The wife of the president usually has no public function at all, except when she had some recognition on her own (e.g. Carla Bruni). In fact, I have it easier remembering wifes of POTUS than wifes of Spanish (or other European) PM.

Comment: Note that it can get even more interesting than that in Europe: You could also ask about gay or lesbian leaders (does it make sense to call [the wife of a female prime minister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B3n%C3%ADna_Le%C3%B3sd%C3%B3ttir) the “first lady”?) and unmarried partners (same-sex or not).

Comment: The husband of Angela Merkel is [Joachim Sauer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joachim_Sauer), and he avoids getting involved in his wife's job as much as he can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most European countries the spouse of political leaders aren't public figures at all and there is no traditional name to designate the spouse of a president so the question does not necessarily arise in these terms. But the problem is actually much broader than this and boils down to the question of who the leader of the executive branch is. For example, when a country has both a president and a prime minister, it's not always obvious who should go to international meetings like the G7, G20, etc. That's particularly relevant for the [European council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Council), which has an important role in the EU.

When the head of state is an hereditary monarch (Belgium, Netherlands, Spain, Sweden, United Kingdom…), that's easy: It's the head of government who is the dominant figure (the monarch and/or foreign minister can play a role in some diplomatic contexts). Then you have some countries where the president isn't a very powerful figure and it's also the head of the government who leads the executive (I think that's the case in Germany, in Italy or in Portugal for example). But there are also countries (Finland, Poland, Romania) where the president and the prime minister openly clashed over this at some point.

---

Finally, since you mentioned France specifically and it is a rather peculiar case, some details on that: The country isn't really a parliamentary democracy. It has a kind of hybrid system that evolved over time since the last constitution was enacted in 1958. Since 1962, the president is elected directly by the people and is a very powerful figure who does not answer to the parliament (the president can actually call up new parliamentary elections at any time, although they have fewer reasons to do it since the length of their term was reduced from seven to five years in 2000).

Usually the president comes first and the parliament follows, as it were, which gives the political system a presidential character but with a prime minister and, paradoxically, without the divided government situation that has become so common in the US. The prime minister does answer to the parliament, which would seem to give the French president much less power over the cabinet than the US president and open up the possibility of constant in-fighting. In practice however, it's traditionally understood (it's not in the constitution!) that the prime minister serves at the pleasure of the president and the parliament always falls in line, at least when the president's party has a majority there (which is most of the time).

But there have nonetheless been two periods of time during which the parliament (and hence the cabinet) on the one hand and the president on the other hand came from opposite side of the political spectrum. In that case, the president cannot control the cabinet (at least not without calling a new election, which neither Mitterrand nor Chirac dared doing right after their party lost one). The prime minister is effectively the leader of the executive branch and takes on much of the role traditionally assumed by the president. The political system is then much closer to a parliamentary democracy but the president still goes to international meetings and the like!

In general, I think the spouse of presidents are somewhat more prominent figures in France than in other European countries and it was already the case long before Carla Bruni. It's never been the case for prime minister's spouses to my knowledge (even when the government is divided as described above) so I don't think many people worried seriously about what to call M. Cresson. In any case, the phrase “*première dame*” (“first lady”) only appeared relatively recently. Previously, the most common way to refer to the spouse of a president would simply be “the spouse/wife of the president” in so many words, which avoids any ambiguity and is reasonably easy to adapt to any situation (it's also the case in Germany for example, I think).

But actually, when using the French language, a much more sensitive question is what to call a female prime minister herself: “*le premier ministre*”, “*la premier ministre*” or “*la première ministre*”. Because of this, it's not uncommon to read something like “*l'époux du premier ministre*” (using the male form for “prime minister”) when referring to the husband of a female prime minister (e.g. Denis Thatcher). No woman has ever been elected president in France but, in 2014, an MP was actually fined €1378 (i.e. deprived of a fourth of his monthly allowance) because he called the president of the lower chamber of parliament (the speaker if you will), “*madame le président*” instead of “*madame la présidente*”.